# Debian 12 install failed - No bootable device found

Tags: debian, boot

I've just installed a Debian 12 on my Dell Latitude 5480 through a bootable USB stick.
It's a basic install, no xorg nor Gnome...
Everything went normal until rebooting.
Now I have this message:

> No bootable device found

I have no idea where this problem comes from.
Note: The secure boot is disabled in the BIOS.
Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out how to fix this issue.

Reboot and press `F2` to enter the bios.

- Go to the `General` section then click `Boot Sequence`
- Make sure the `UEFI` option is checked.
- click the `Add Boot Option` button
- on the `Add Boot Option` panel click the `File Name` button
- Browse to the `shimx64.efi` file and click `Ok`
- Enter a name in the `Boot Option Name` field then click `Ok`.
- Save the changes and reboot

Here is a [step by step](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000141125/xps-13-9343-how-to-install-ubuntu-developer-edition-14-04-on-a-dell-pc-configured-for-the-unified-extensible-firmware-interface-uefi-bios) for Ubuntu 15.04.
It might have some slight differences against Debian but it's basically the same.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

There are a view options to try out.

1. When the laptop starts, press <kbd>F12</kbd> to access the boot menu.
   Here, you can check if your devices are listed for startup to select.
2. Resetting the BIOS to UEFI Boot(Reverting the system to UEFI boot mode):

- Power on the turned-off system and press <kbd>F2</kbd> to enter the BIOS setup menu.
- Select `Boot sequence`.
- Change the option from `Legacy` to `UEFI` and then select `Apply` in the bottom-right corner.
  [image]
- Select `Advanced boot options` and disable `Enable Legacy Operation ROMs`, then choose `Apply` in the bottom-right corner.
  [image]
- Select `Secure Boot`, then choose `Secure Boot Enable`.
- Change the option from `Disabled` to `Enabled` and select `Apply` in the bottom-right corner.
  [image]
- Choose `Exit` in the bottom-right corner and wait for the system to restart.

3. Reset the BIOS to factory/default settings, and try to boot again.